# Вывод разницы во времени текстом

Tags: python, datetime

Всех приветствую. Я бы хотел узнать есть ли такая библиотека на python, чтобы код выводил промежуток времени **словами**, например разница в 13 сек, и скрипт выводит `меньше минуты назад` или же разница ровна 2 дня, то скрипт выводит `более 2 дней`

Comment: Написать самому такую функцию -  30 минут работы, с тестированием и глубокой отладкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с датами и промежутками времени удобно использовать стандартный модуль [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). В данном случае нужно вычесть две сравниваемые даты в виде `datetime` (в примере ниже - `datetime.now() - datetime(2021, 7, 14, 8, 0)` - из текущей даты/времени вычесть 14.07.2021 8:00), результатом будет `timedelta` (разница времени), эту дельту сравнивать с разными промежутками времени, в зависимости от результата выводить то что вам нужно, пример:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def text_delta(t: timedelta) -> str:
    if t < timedelta(minutes=1):
        return "меньше минуты назад"
    elif t < timedelta(hours=1):
        return f"{t.total_seconds() // 60:.0f} минут назад"
    elif t < timedelta(days=1):
        return f"{t.total_seconds() // 3600:.0f} часов назад"
    elif t < timedelta(days=30):
        return f"{t.days} дней назад"
    elif t < timedelta(days=365):
        return f"{t.days // 30} месяцев назад"
    else:
        return f"{t.days // 365} лет назад"


print(text_delta(datetime.now() - datetime(2021, 7, 14, 8, 0)))
print(text_delta(timedelta(seconds=13)))
print(text_delta(timedelta(minutes=13)))
print(text_delta(timedelta(hours=13)))
print(text_delta(timedelta(days=13)))
print(text_delta(timedelta(days=30*3)))
print(text_delta(timedelta(days=365*3)))
```

Вывод:

```
2 часов назад
меньше минуты назад
13 минут назад
13 часов назад
13 дней назад
3 месяцев назад
3 лет назад
```

Для правильного склонения часов/минут и т.д. можно использовать pymorphy2: [Согласование слов с числительными](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/guide.html#id8)

Answer (score 0):

нет библиотеки такой нет.
Но ты можешь написать простой код который может вычислять время.
просто вычти время или дату просто вычти из нынешней даты дату высланного сообщения и всё!
вот как это осуществить простейший пример на основе месяцев:

```
from datetime import datetime
month_now = datetime.today().month #вместо month можно поставить year или day
last = 5 #Пример месяца отправленного сообщения
end = month_now - last #Вычисляем пройденное время, если это было в прошлом году то придется вычислять еще и год
```

Comment: Не надо удалять ответ и добавлять новый такой же, вы можете редактировать ответ, чтобы улучшить. Если у вас проблемы с форматированием ответа - просто подождите, кто-нибудь из опытных участников форума ваш ответ отредактирует.

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться, чтобы знать как писать в ответах так, чтобы все не сливалось в одни блок текста: [Справка по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)